# Generate a RecursionError

Tags: code-golf, recursion, error-message

Write the shortest possible code cause an error due to recursion too deep

Example error in [python](/questions/tagged/python)

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Example error in [c](/questions/tagged/c)

```
Segmentation fault
```

My Python version (15 bytes):

```python
def f():f()
f()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf. Please avoid [making assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/43319). It is highly recommended to first post proposed challenges in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges). I hope you'll stick with us and have an enjoyable time here.

Comment: [Note that challenges that require the answers to be in a specific language are generally discouraged.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/python/info)

Comment: @xnor Oh, I did not read that correctly. Retracted my close vote. (To the challenge author, sorry for any confusion :p)

Comment: I think this is an interesting puzzle in Python if it has an answer. Do you know if there's indeed something shorter?

Comment: An interesting idea is to do something with recursive lists like `l=[];l+=l,;l<l`, but this 14-byter doesn't work, and any fixes seem to make it longer.

Comment: @adam That's better?

Comment: @Danis Not really. Now that it isn't Python-specific we hit the problem of making assumptions about language features. What kind of errors are allowed? Is erroring due to running out of memory acceptable? Is crashing/quitting/halting acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

```apl
F
F
```

A 1-byte header separated by a line break byte from by a 1-byte body which calls the function itself. This type of function doesn't have tail call optimisation, so this fails when memory runs out.

Anonymous lambdas do have [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33923/5306507), but we can prevent that:

```apl
{-∇⍵}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1r3UUf7o96ttYb//wMA)

`{`…`}1` call an anonymous lambda with an argument of 1:

`⍵` the argument

`∇` recurse on that

`-` negate the result

We never actually reach the negation before running out of memory, but it is needed to avoid the optimisation.

Comment: [Either way](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2035/43319).

Comment: In Python, JS and probably a couple of other languages, any lambda / anonymous function that includes a reference to itself (so typically any recursive function) _must_ be explicitly named (e.g. `f=lambda` or `f=_=>`) and the extra bytes are taken into account for the final score, although this is otherwise not required. So I guess the same logic should apply here?

Comment: @Arnauld Yeah, makes sense.

Comment: @Arnauld Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 15 bytes

```python
exec('()'*9999)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7UiNVlDXUNTXcsSCDT//wcA)

An alternative that doesn't use functions. Unfortunately `RecursionError` does not exist in Python 2 so we can't cut the brackets in `exec`.

### Python 3.8, 18 bytes

```python
exec(s:='exec(s)')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P7UiNVmj2MpWHcLQVNf8/x8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```python
def f(x):x(x)
f(f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNo0LTqgJIcKVppGn@/w8A)